How to embed Python to .Net?
I tried to embed Python to .Net using pythonnet based on the docs here and here.
Here are my code
Runtime.PythonDLL = @"D:\Dev\Console\.conda\python311.dll";
PythonEngine.Initialize();
dynamic sys = Py.Import("sys");
Console.WriteLine("Python version: " + sys.version);

.conda is virtual environment I created using VSCode.
I get this error message.

System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for
'Delegates' threw an exception.' DllNotFoundException: Could not load
D:\Dev\Console.conda\python311.dll. Win32Exception: The specified
module could not be found.

Thanks.

Here how I embed virtual Python environment to .net
string pathToVirtualEnv = "";
if (Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    pathToVirtualEnv = Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.Parent.Parent.FullName + @"\.conda\";
}
else
{
    //TODO: Define your virtual env path here
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

// be sure not to overwrite your existing "PATH" environmental variable.
var path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH").TrimEnd(';');
path = string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) ? pathToVirtualEnv : path + ";" + pathToVirtualEnv;
var process = EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process;
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", path, process);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", pathToVirtualEnv, process);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONHOME", pathToVirtualEnv, process);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONPATH", $"{pathToVirtualEnv}\\Lib\\site-packages;{pathToVirtualEnv}\\Lib", process);

Runtime.PythonDLL = pathToVirtualEnv + @"python311.dll";

PythonEngine.PythonHome = pathToVirtualEnv;
PythonEngine.PythonPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONPATH", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

PythonEngine.Initialize();
dynamic sys = Py.Import("sys");
Console.WriteLine("Python version: " + sys.version);

